# node pg.connect never calling its callback, how to debug?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, express

So I have a working express server talking to a postgres backend running on a heroku server.  I'm trying to move to AWS.  On AWS I think I have everything set up correctly.  I have my express server running (under PM2 though that shouldn't make a difference.  I can SSH into the ec2 and from there launch a psql and connect to the DB without any issues, I've created my schema no problem.

However my app is not working with the DB, Most likely its not even connecting but I'm getting nothing back. not even a timeout.  I first tried with env variables to set everything up but decided to put the user/password in the code.

my express code looks like this obviously i changed the values for the post but they are the same values
I use on the psql command line

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

const db = new Client({
              user: 'myUserName',
              host: 'myHostName',
              password: 'myPassword',
    });
    
    console.log("about to connect to the DB");
    db.connect(err => {
            if (err) {
                    console.error('connection error', err.stack)
            } else {
                    console.log('connected')
            }
    }
    );
```

In my logs I get the line "about to connect to the DB" but I never get anything else I do not
get the error nor the success line.

how do I see what's wrong?  with no feedback I'm stuck. Is there something I can check in aws?
I doubt its a security group issue since psql works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I had a bad version/installation of Node.  I created a new instance on AWS and installed Node 12.x instead of "latest"  which was 14.x and its working fine now.